# Changing opacity of inactive windows in KDE

Tags: kubuntu, kde, window, plasma

Is there a way to set a customization in Plasma environment so that inactive windows will have opacity 30%?

I know one can set specific titlebar colors for active and inactive windows . But I could not find anything about opacity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this via a generic Window Rule that covers all windows.

System Settings > Workspace Appearance and Behaviour > Window Behaviour > Window Rules > New…

You probably want to limit Window matching rules, so that (e.g.) the panel will not have its opacity changed. I'm not really sure which you want. Perhaps chose "Normal Window" to start with, and possibly "Dialogue Window" if you like.

Change tabs to "Appearance & Fixes", then check Active opacity > Force; 100%. Also check Inactive opacity > Force; 30%. Click OK then Apply.

[image]

Comment: My ideas were imprisoned in color settings. thnx

Comment: No worries. I love the power and customisability of KDE, but I agree that sometimes the settings are a bit hard to find.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. What wonders me is that «Doesn't apply» menu — which ought to be set instead of «force; 100%» — doesn't work to active window, it's probably a bug.

Comment: @Hi-Angel What's `Doesn't apply`? Is that `Do Not Affect`? If so, that just means "don't touch these settings at all".

Comment: @Sparhawk yeah, right, I have it localized, so I launched it with `LANG=C`. «Do not affect» means either «Do not affect active windows», in which case it'd have opacity 100%, because the 70% set for inactive windows only; or «Do not affect by opacity» in which case they would be invisible at all. The same behavior ought to be if the «Active opacity» checkbox not set. I'll report a bug when I figure out another irrelevant problem here.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I'm not sure if I understand totally, but I think you are saying that you shouldn't need to set the `Active opacity`? I haven't tested, but either logic makes sense to me. i.e. if it's unset, then make the window inactive, and it's 30%. Now activate it, and nothing changes; it's still 30%. Alternatively, I can imagine it "resetting" to the default of 100% when it's active again. (Again, I haven't tested.)

Comment: @Sparhawk ah, I see what you mean. You mean it's like a state machine: when it's unset, all inactive windows become transparent, then you choose inactive window, thus making it active one, and its opacity doesn't change because the checkbox does not say to force it. Well, it's a bad usability anyway, because to find the logic you have go trough the algorithm, whilst the checkboxes say definitely whether the rule applied to active, or inactive ones. What bothers me also: wouldn't there be an additional *unneded* computation of background+content for every 100% opacity window.

Comment: @Hi-Angel TBH I don't really know. I'm just saying that either way I can imagine the devs justifying it as a feature, not a bug… :)