# Change title bar's color on focus in Compiz

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, window, focus

When the focus is gained by a window, I want

1. title bar of this active window to be red,
2. opacity of inactive windows to be decreased. ([solution for KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432501/changing-opacity-of-inactive-windows-in-kde))

Are these possible on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Unity.

Note: I have tried [GNOME Color Chooser](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-color-chooser/), it did not work for Compiz.